# Animate the call to action

Tags: liveagent

When initiating the Live Agent CTA I'm calling

```
liveagent.showWhenOnline(id, onlineButton);
```

This will show the onlineButton. At this point I need to animate the onlineButton, is there a way of doing this? 
Does the showWhenOnline() method take a callback function or trigger an event? 
Any suggestions gratefully received.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement a callback by using `addButtonEventHandler` method of liveagent JS object. Please refer to this Salesforce link for details.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_automated_chat_invitations_code_sample.htm

```
.......
.......
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://c.la2w1.salesforceliveagent.com/content/g/js/38.0/deployment.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function btnEventHandler(e){
            if(e == liveagent.BUTTON_EVENT.BUTTON_AVAILABLE){
                alert("Available!");
            }else if(e == liveagent.BUTTON_EVENT.BUTTON_UNAVAILABLE){
                alert("Gone!");
            }
        }
        liveagent.addButtonEventHandler('573i00000006vIn', btnEventHandler);    
        liveagent.init('https://d.la2w1.salesforceliveagent.com/chat', '572i00000006rlJ', '00Di0000000inoh');
    </script>
```